# Usage and omission of "some"

Tags: grammar

can anyone please tell me if I can leave out "***some***" in the following sentence?

Here is the example:

Hey John, give me ***(some)*** books that have great stories.

To me the word ***"some"*** is optional. I can leave it out. Can anyone please answer this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is certainly true that "Give me books that contain good stories" and "Give me some books that contain good stories" are **both** grammatical. They have, however, somewhat different meanings. The meaning of the first may vary depending on context, but, absent context, it demands only books containing good stories now and in the future. The second merely demands more than one book containing good stories in the immediate present. If all you want is to read a few books containing good stories over the weekend, the first sentence is not idiomatic.